# Why is the output repeating twice?

Tags: coldfusion

I have this query (yes is long , working on making it better)

```
<cfquery datasource="Intranet" name="getHighestDeptAverage">
DECLARE @today DATETIME
SET @today = '2014-04-13'

  ;with CTE as(
    Select d.csedept_name,d.csedept_id, Average = CASE WHEN d.csedept_question5 IS NULL
    THEN (Select AVG(((cast(c.rating1 as Float)+ cast(c.rating2 as Float)+cast (c.rating3 as Float)+cast(c.rating4 as Float))/4))
        From intranet.dbo.CSEReduxResponses c
        Where c.employeedept = d.csedept_id
        AND c.execoffice_status > 0
        AND month(approveddate) = MONTH(@today))
    ELSE (Select AVG(((cast(c.rating1 as Float)+ cast(c.rating2 as Float)+cast (c.rating3 as Float)+cast(c.rating4 as Float)+cast(c.rating5 as Float))/5))
        From intranet.dbo.CSEReduxResponses c
        Where c.employeedept = d.csedept_id
        AND c.execoffice_status > 0
        AND month(approveddate) = MONTH(@today))
    END
from Intranet.dbo.CSEReduxDepts d
)
Select Top 2 Ranks = RANK() Over(Order By Average DESC),* 
from CTE
</cfquery>
```

I want to output the top two ranks,
This is what im doing:

```
<cfoutput query="getMaxstars">

    <cfif rnk eq 1>

        <cfset average_rating_max = total_stars>
        <cfset average_rating_dept = first_name>
        <cfset average_rating_dept_last_name = last_name>
    </cfif>

       <cfif rnk eq 2>

        <cfset average_rating_max_runnerup = total_stars>
        <cfset average_rating_dept_runnerup = first_name>
        <cfset average_rating_dept_runnerup_last_name = last_name>
    </cfif>

</cfoutput>
  <cfoutput query="getHighestDeptAverage">
     <h3>Winner: Department- #highest_dept_name_average#</h3>
     <h3>Average:  #hihest_dept_average# </h3>
     <h4>Runner-up: Department- #highest_dept_name_runnerup# </h4>
     <h4> Average: #highest_dept_name_average_runnerup# </h4>
  </cfoutput>
```

Right now is outputing the result twice, and I only would like it to output
once. I feel it should work since I do have another query that I do the same 
if and output so I not sure why is outputing twice?

Comment: Without reading any of your code and noticing that the question has been answered, I suggest that you check out the group attribute of cfoutput.  It often solves the problem of repeating output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm reading your question and code right, I believe you'll want to remove

```
 query="getHighestDeptAverage"
```

from your second <cfoutput>.

You're not returning your query results here, but your have two results, therefore the second output.